# How to apply a function to multiple columns that iterates through each row

Tags: python, pandas

**Data**

I have a dataset that shows up-to-date bookings data grouped by company and month (empty values are NaNs)

```
company    month  year_ly  bookings_ly  year_ty  bookings_ty 
company a  1      2018     432          2019     253         
company a  2      2018     265          2019     635         
company a  3      2018     345          2019     525         
company a  4      2018     233          2019              
company a  5      2018     7664         2019             
...        ...    ...      ...          ...      ...         
company a  12     2018     224          2019     321         
company b  1      2018     543          2019     576        
company b  2      2018     23           2019     43          
company b  3      2018     64           2019     156
company b  4      2018     143          2019     
company b  5      2018     41           2019              
company b  6      2018     90           2019     
...        ...    ...      ...          ...      ...
```

**What I want**

I'd like to create a column or update the `bookings_ty` column where value is `NaN` (whichever is easier) that applies the following calculation for each row (grouped by company):

`((SUM of previous 3 rows (or months) of bookings_ty)
 /(SUM of previous 3 rows (or months) of bookings_ly))
* bookings_ly`

Where a row's `bookings_ty` is NaN, I'd like that iteration of the formula to take the newly calculated field as part of its `bookings_ty` so essentially what the formula should do is populate NaN values in `bookings_ty`.

**My attempt**

```
df_bkgs.set_index(['operator', 'month'], inplace=True)

def calc(df_bkgs):
    df_bkgs['bookings_calc'] = df_bkgs['bookings_ty'].copy
    df_bkgs['bookings_ty_l3m'] = df_bkgs.groupby(level=0)['bookings_ty'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1) + x.shift(2) + x.shift(3) )
    df_bkgs['bookings_ly_l3m'] = df_bkgs.groupby(level=0)['bookings_ly'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1) + x.shift(2) + x.shift(3) )
    df_bkgs['bookings_factor'] = df_bkgs['bookings_ty_l3m']/df_bkgs['bookings_ly_l3m']
    df_bkgs['bookings_calc'] = df_bkgs['bookings_factor'] * df_bkgs['bookings_ly']
    return df_bkgs

df_bkgs.groupby(level=0).apply(calc)

import numpy as np
df['bookings_calc'] = np.where(df['bookings_ty']isna(), df['bookings_calc'], df['bookings_ty'])
```

Issue with this code is that it generates the calculated field for only the first empty/NaN `bookings_ty`. What I'd like is for there to be an iteration or loop type process that then takes the previous 3 rows in the group and if the `bookings_ty` is empty/NaN then take the calculated field of that row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  I made a function which found the last 3 records in your dataframe by row.  note I had to create a column named index to do this as you can't access the index (as far as I know) within an apply statement.

```
# dataframe is named f
   company  month  year_ly  bookings_ly  year_ty  bookings_ty
0        a      1     2018          432     2019        253.0
1        a      2     2018          265     2019        635.0
2        a      3     2018          345     2019        525.0
3        a      4     2018          233     2019          NaN
4        a      5     2018         7664     2019          NaN
5        a     12     2018          224     2019        321.0
6        b      1     2018          543     2019        576.0
7        b      2     2018           23     2019         43.0
8        b      3     2018           64     2019        156.0
9        b      4     2018          143     2019          NaN
10       b      5     2018           41     2019          NaN
11       b      6     2018           90     2019          NaN

f.reset_index(inplace=True)

def aggFunct(row, df, last=3):

    series = df.loc[(df['index'] < row['index']) & (df['index'] >= row['index'] - last), 'bookings_ty'].fillna(0)

    ssum = series.sum()

    return ssum

f.loc[f['bookings_ty'].isna(),'bookings_ty'] = f[f['bookings_ty'].isna()].apply(aggFunct, df=f, axis=1)

f.drop('index',axis=1,inplace=True)

f
   company  month  year_ly  bookings_ly  year_ty  bookings_ty
0        a      1     2018          432     2019        253.0
1        a      2     2018          265     2019        635.0
2        a      3     2018          345     2019        525.0
3        a      4     2018          233     2019       1413.0
4        a      5     2018         7664     2019       1160.0
5        a     12     2018          224     2019        321.0
6        b      1     2018          543     2019        576.0
7        b      2     2018           23     2019         43.0
8        b      3     2018           64     2019        156.0
9        b      4     2018          143     2019        775.0
10       b      5     2018           41     2019        199.0
11       b      6     2018           90     2019        156.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many companies you have in your table, I might be inclined to run this on Excel as opposed to doing this on pandas. Iterating through the rows might be slow, but if speed is not a concern, the following solution should work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data_file.xlsx')  # <-- name of your file.

companies = pd.unique(df.company)
months = pd.unique(df.month)

for c in companies:
    for m in months:
        # slice a single row 
        df_row= df[(df['company']==c) & (df['month']==m)]
        val = df_slice.bookings_ty.values[0]
        if np.isnan(val):
            # get the index of the row
            idx = df_row.index[0]
            df1 = df.copy()

            df1 = df1[(df1['company']==c) & (df1['month'].isin([m for m in range(m-3,m)]))]
            ratio = df1.bookings_ty.sum() / df1.bookings_ly.sum()
            projected_value = df_slice.bookings_ly.values[0] * ratio
            df.loc[idx, 'bookings_ty'] = projected_value
        else:
            pass

print(df)
```

if we can assume that the DataFrame is always sorted by 'company' and then by 'month', then we can use the following approach, there is a 20-fold improvement (0.003s vs. 0.07s) with my sample data of 24 rows.

```
df = pd.read_excel('data_file.xlsx')   # your input file
ly = df.bookings_ly.values.tolist()
ty = df.bookings_ty.values.tolist()
for val in ty:
    if np.isnan(val):
        idx = ty.index(val) # returns the index of the first 'nan' found
        ratio = sum(ty[idx-3:idx])/sum(ly[idx-3:idx])
        ty[idx] = ratio * ly[idx]

df['bookings_ty'] = ty
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you may be right, iterating through the rows is taking a lot of time...

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#sort values if not
df = df.sort_values(['company', 'year_ty', 'month']).reset_index(drop=True)

def process(x):
    while x['bookings_ty'].isnull().any():
        x['bookings_ty'] = np.where((x['bookings_ty'].isnull()),
                                    (x['bookings_ty'].shift(1) +
                                     x['bookings_ty'].shift(2) +
                                    x['bookings_ty'].shift(3)) /
                                   (x['bookings_ly'].shift(1) +
                                    x['bookings_ly'].shift(2) +
                                    x['bookings_ly'].shift(3)) *
                                    x['bookings_ly'],  x['bookings_ty'])
    return x

df = df.groupby(['company']).apply(lambda x: process(x))

#convert to int64 if needed or stay with float values
df['bookings_ty'] = df['bookings_ty'].astype(np.int64)
print(df)
```

**initial DF:**

```
      company  month  year_ly  bookings_ly  year_ty  bookings_ty
0   company_a      1     2018          432     2019          253
1   company_a      2     2018          265     2019          635
2   company_a      3     2018          345     2019          525
3   company_a      4     2018          233     2019          NaN
4   company_a      5     2018         7664     2019          NaN
5   company_a     12     2018          224     2019          321
6   company_b      1     2018          543     2019          576
7   company_b      2     2018           23     2019           43
8   company_b      3     2018           64     2019          156
9   company_b      4     2018          143     2019          NaN
10  company_b      5     2018           41     2019          NaN
11  company_b      6     2018           90     2019          NaN
```

**result:**

```
      company  month  year_ly  bookings_ly  year_ty  bookings_ty   
0   company_a      1     2018          432     2019          253   
1   company_a      2     2018          265     2019          635   
2   company_a      3     2018          345     2019          525   
3   company_a      4     2018          233     2019          315 **
4   company_a      5     2018         7664     2019        13418 **
5   company_a     12     2018          224     2019          321   
6   company_b      1     2018          543     2019          576   
7   company_b      2     2018           23     2019           43   
8   company_b      3     2018           64     2019          156   
9   company_b      4     2018          143     2019          175 **
10  company_b      5     2018           41     2019           66 **
11  company_b      6     2018           90     2019          144 **
```

---

In case of you want another rolling month or maybe a NaN value could exist at the beginning of each company, you could use this generic solution:

```
df = df.sort_values(['company', 'year_ty', 'month']).reset_index(drop=True)

def process(x, m):
    idx = (x.loc[x['bookings_ty'].isnull()].index.to_list())
    for i in idx:
        id = i - x.index[0]
        start = 0 if id < m  else id - m
        sum_ty = sum(x['bookings_ty'].to_list()[start:id])
        sum_ly = sum(x['bookings_ly'].to_list()[start:id])
        ly = x.at[i, 'bookings_ly']
        x.at[i, 'bookings_ty'] = sum_ty / sum_ly * ly
    return x

rolling_month = 3
df = df.groupby(['company']).apply(lambda x: process(x, rolling_month))

df['bookings_ty'] = df['bookings_ty'].astype(np.int64)
print(df)
```

---

**initial df:**

```
      company  month  year_ly  bookings_ly  year_ty  bookings_ty
0   company_a      1     2018          432     2019        253.0
1   company_a      2     2018          265     2019        635.0
2   company_a      3     2018          345     2019          NaN
3   company_a      4     2018          233     2019          NaN
4   company_a      5     2018         7664     2019          NaN
5   company_a     12     2018          224     2019        321.0
6   company_b      1     2018          543     2019        576.0
7   company_b      2     2018           23     2019         43.0
8   company_b      3     2018           64     2019        156.0
9   company_b      4     2018          143     2019          NaN
10  company_b      5     2018           41     2019          NaN
11  company_b      6     2018           90     2019          NaN
```

**final result:**

```
  company  month  year_ly  bookings_ly  year_ty  bookings_ty
0   company_a      1     2018          432     2019          253
1   company_a      2     2018          265     2019          635
2   company_a      3     2018          345     2019          439  ** work only with 2 previous rows
3   company_a      4     2018          233     2019          296  **
4   company_a      5     2018         7664     2019        12467  **
5   company_a     12     2018          224     2019          321
6   company_b      1     2018          543     2019          576
7   company_b      2     2018           23     2019           43
8   company_b      3     2018           64     2019          156
9   company_b      4     2018          143     2019          175 **
10  company_b      5     2018           41     2019           66 **
11  company_b      6     2018           90     2019          144 **
```

if you want to speed up the process you could try:

```
df.set_index(['company'], inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(level=(0)).apply(lambda x: process(x))
```

instead of

```
df = df.groupby(['company']).apply(lambda x: process(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - do you know how I could speed this up? I've got about 4000 rows and would want to apply this function to 2 or 3 extra columns as well? Any ideas?

Comment: see the end of my answer, you could try to set index before the groupby